# GeoDjango + Geoserver + OpenLayers for dynamic mapping

Tags: openlayers, geodjango, geoserver

I'm currently developing a web mapping application using Django/GeoDjango, Postgres/PostGIS, and OpenLayers. The end aim is to enable the analysis of property data, so I'm needing to visualise upwards of 30,000 polygons at a time. I'm wondering about my options for dynamically generating thematic maps with this many polygons. Currently I visualising some GeoJSON layers that contain as many as 60 geometries, but I'm not sure of the upward limit for GeoJSON. If WMS is the way to go, can Geoserver be used with Django view functions to dynamically create and symbolise map layers? With a geoserver WMS is it possible to select multiple features on map? Is it also possible to edit feature information?

Thanks in advance for any advice on this.

Ro

Answer (score 2):

No doubt, go for WMS and GeoServer. You can easily visualize such count of polygons with them (with GeoJSON, reasonable limit is up to couple of hundred features). You can edit feature information over WFS-T protocol, which is also supported by GeoServer; and there are couple of different techniques to select features on map (like combination of WMS+WFS).

Comment: Thanks for the reply and info. With GeoServer WMS, can I use Django view functions to create GeoQuerySets and display only the results of those queries? Also, is there an upper recommended limit for displaying features with WFS? Thanks again.